# how can i detect when a user adds a keyboard language in settings

Tags: ios, settings, uikeyboard

I want to receive a notification when the user adds a new keyboard language in the general settings and my application is in background.

Can anyone advise what code is needed to achieve this, or what preference key i should look for.

I have tried :-

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
selector:@selector(defaultsChanged:)
name:NSUserDefaultsDidChangeNotification
object:nil];
```

Comment: if all else fails, you can just check if a new language has been added whenever the app goes to foreground.

Comment: can you be more specific - perhaps a code example - how does checking the language selection tell me if the user loaded a new keyboard?

Comment: how does a version control system know if i added a file? ;)

Comment: sorry michael i don't understand your comment about version control. i simply want to know within my app if the main phone settings have been changed, and specifically whether a new keyboard language has been added - e.g chinese or turkish or korean for example. Its different to the user language setting i believe, as its possible to have french language but not a french keyboard loaded. do you understand my problem? how do i get a notification of the settings being changed while my application is in background mode.